# Ignore files for outputHashing

Tags: angular

I have an angular app that uses webcomponents for icons (which are svgs). I have to pull those svgs into my app manually like this:

```
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/i18l",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/manifest.json",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "./node_modules/@something/common-webcomponents/dist/something-webcomponents/svg-icons",
                "output": "/svg-icons/"
              }
            ],
```

The problem is the hashing messes with the path of the svg's as well. I still want the outputHashing on everything else, but I want to exclude these svg assets. Looking at the documentation for angular ([here](https://angular.io/cli/build)) it says the valid options are `none|all|media|bundles`. Frankly I don't know what those mean and couldn't find a more in-depth explanation. Currently it's set to `all` for me for prod builds, which I want, but with a few exceptions. Is it possible to exclude a "glob" of files from output hashing?